# How to read private messages with PRAW?

Tags: python, praw

I'm creating a Reddit bot with praw, and I want to have the bot do things based on private messages sent to it. I searched the documentation for a bit, but couldn't find anything on reading private messages, only sending them. I want to get both the title and the content of the message. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't find it in the docs, but a friend who knows a bit of raw helped me out.

Use `for message in r.inbox.messages()` (where r is an instance of reddit) to get the messages.

Use `message.text` to get the content, and `message.subject` to get the title.